# Offset columns while reordering columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following example dataset:

```
set.seed (1988)
data <- matrix(sample(1:100, 80), 5, 16)
colnames(data) <- paste0("V", 1:16)

V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15  V16
56   40   75   78   33   82   97   23   99    16    26    69    60    50    93    10
45   30   71    1   64   51   46   47   81    70     8    53    34     4    29     9
37   65   73   54   39   79   55   95   96    44    43     3    41    49    22    17
18   83   14   38   68   88   63    5   28    36    35    85    72    52    86     7
15   13   92   62   58   57   25   84   89    48    74    20    59    12    76    19
```

I want to **reorder** the columns and the **desired** output is something like this,

```
redata <- data[ , c(1:2, 11:12, 3:4, 13:14, 5:6, 15:16, 7:10)]

V1   V2   V11  V12  V3   V4   V13  V14  V5    V6    V15   V16   V7    V8    V9    V10
56   40   26   69   75   78   60   50   33    82    93    10    97    23    99    16
45   30    8   53   71    1   34    4   64    51    29     9    46    47    81    70
37   65   43    3   73   54   41   49   39    79    22    17    55    95    96    44
18   83   35   85   14   38   72   52   68    88    86     7    63     5    28    36
15   13   74   20   92   62   59   12   58    57    76    19    25    84    89    48
```

where column 11 & 12 comes after columns 1 & 2, column 13 & 14 comes after columns 3 & 4 and so on...

- I have hundreds of columns like this in the actual data and hence, it'll be very difficult to give the column index or the name

I have looked upon several related threads in  this site but couldn't find any relevant ones.

Comment: I don't understand what's the question

Comment: please explain it more detail

Comment: you need to think about the pattern of the order. Once you're able to explain it in detail, you'll probably know yourself how to implement it

Comment: @docendodiscimus I have tried to re-frame second part of the question. I hope it's more readable now.

Comment: What is the relationship between these columns that is determining that they need to be placed next to each other? Why are columns 11 and 12 being placed between 2 and 3? You say there is no set ordering criteria, yet in your example it always seems to be two columns, then the columns offset from those by 10. Is this a consistent pattern or is there other criteria coming into play that is not represented in your example?

Comment: @MattJewett The columns to be placed alongside are of similar types in pairs (3&4 are similar to 11 &12 and so on) which will later be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Not super elegant but it works for your example, and hopefully for your full data:

```
col_order <- c(1,2,11,12,3,4,13,14,5,6,15,16,7,8,17,18,9,10,19,20)
i <- 1
while(i < ncol(data)/20){
  col_order <- c(col_order,col_order+20)
  i <- i+1  
}
col_order <- intersect(col_order,1:ncol(data))
data_new <- data[,col_order]
```